# Cómo crear una gráfica superpuesta?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Estoy intentando construir un gráfico que mida la distribución normal de una columna de datos de un df,actualmente tengo un gráfico con barras,como puedo crear otro encima lineal para ver la dn??

````
df['SalePrice'].hist()
df['SalePrice'].subplot.kde()```
````

Comment: Puedes hacer dos plots uno con la columna padre y la columna primera a visualiza, y otro con la columna padre y la columna de por encime. Cuabdo hagas `show()` vas a a ver los dos, uno encima de otro.

Comment: Estoy probando esto,pero no funciona tengo que asignar variables a los plots y meterlas dentro de show??   ```df['SalePrice'].plot.hist()
df['SalePrice'].plot.kde()
plt.show()```

Comment: Haz, `plt.plot(dfp,dfa); plt.plot(dfp,dfb); plt.show`. Donde los (;) separan las lineas de código, `dfp` es el dataframe padre osea x en el gráfico, y `dfa` y `dfb` son los dataframes que se cruzarán.

Comment: Pero es que no tengo 3 dataframes,tengo solo 1 y lo que quiero es sacar un grafico superpuesto de dos graficas de una columna